# Fourier multiplier theorem on Lebesgue spaces

Tags: analysis, notation, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to understand the hypothesis of Marcinkiewicz-Mihlin-Hörmander multiplier theorem. See for instance **Theorem A** in following [paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/JEDP_1995____A16_0.pdf) of Elias Stain.

**Theorem A**: Assume that $m: (0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ satisfies the following
$$|m^{(j)}(x)| \leq C x^{-j}\tag{1}$$ for $0 \leq j \leq k$ and $k>d/2.$
Or more generally
$$ \sup_{t>0} \left\|\chi m(t \cdot)\right\|_{H^{\alpha}}< \infty\tag{2} $$
where $\chi$ is a non-zero smooth cut-off function of compact support which vanishes near the origin and $\|f\|_{H^s} =\|(1+ |\cdot|^2)^{s/2} \hat{f}\|_{L^2}.$

Then Fourier-multiplier operator $\widehat{Tf}= m(|\xi|^2) \hat{f}$ is bounded on $L^p (\mathbb R^d)$ for $1<p< \infty.$

My questions are:

1. Why condition (1) implies (2) in the Theorem?
2. How has the theorem been developed historically? (I mean version of Marcinkiewicz theorem  1939, version of  Mihim  1957, and finally version of Hormander 1960.)